# Simple Build of Libavcodec.so and libavformat.so on Mac

Tags: android, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav, libavformat

Who needs ffmpeg?  Not me.  What I need is to be able to decode a video stream along with its audio stream, so that can put the frames on an opengl surface in sync with the audio.

FFmpeg is a tool that transcodes video.  That is not what I need.  I need its libraries.

The problem is that every example for building FFmpeg includes junk I just dont need.  The latest example I wasted my time on:

https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg

uses things like freetype2 that I really, REALLY, do not need.  Whats more annoying is that it wont even build as described because the example references freetype, not freetype2 so the build steps are broken.  Don't even get me started on the problems I had with libtool.

The kicker is finding libav.org, where they describe on their about page the chaos in the ffmpeg project.  Perhaps that is why this is so difficult.

So, should it be so hard to build just the shared libs?  Can someone point me to some documentation, or a tutorial that works?  I admit that this is new territory for me but all I have found using Google is chaos.

Comment: Get the ffmpeg source and then refer to `./configure --help`. You can enable or disable almost any component (such as `--disable-programs`).